# How do you install avconv on Ubuntu Server 13.04?

Tags: server, sound, video, avconv

I've searched and searched, but I can't find anything, besides compiling it, which gives me an error about ASM.

Comment: In the future, you should post the error as it usually compiles just fine after installing all dependencies. Although, the recommended method is apt-get.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can install avconv with package [libav-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=raring&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=avconv)

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this doesn't work in Ubuntu > v14 as there's no libav-tools package.  Follow the advice below by @Seandex

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, those answer won't work on Bionic version because FFmpeg won't include the avahi libraries in the package. you will have to install libav-tools manually 
in order to get avconv_cli

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg  #requirement to run avahi
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/348889634/libav-tools_3.4.1-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libav-tools_3.4.1-1_all.deb
```

I'm adding this answer here because this topic looks like the only one discusses the avconv but the answers are not for the later versions of Ubuntu distro.
But why would you if you could get the same result from ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. But to be clear, you still need to have ffmpeg installed before installing the deb above.

Comment: @JamesBradbury You are correct. because libav-tools depends on FFmpeg. It was for some people who were expecting FFmpeg includes libav-tools however, I should've been mentioned FFmpeg to be as clear as possible and error free. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libav-tools
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this doesn't work in Ubuntu > v14 as there's no libav-tools package

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

This will also install the libav-tools by default